# Combining MediaWiki API:Users and API:Usercontribs

Tags: api, mediawiki, difference, mediawiki-api

I have a list of users. I am trying to retrieve their registration, editcount and gender using API:Users, and contribution data using API:Usercontribs.

Because of being gentle with the API, I have to put a bunch of usernames in each request, and I need to match their userIDs in order to be able to merge the results from the two APIs.

I faced an strange problem: there are a fair number of users with different userIDs retrieved by each method. E.g., if you query data for username "December21st2012Freak" from API:Users, you'll get userID 14281125, but requesting the same username from API:Usercontribs, the userID returns as 10141256.
Another example is username "The Sunshine Man", which has userID 4857299 retrieved bu API:Users and userID 4302884 retrieved by API:Usercontribs.

I don't understand why there is such an inconsistency.

Here are exact queries:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=users&ususers=December21st2012Freak|The%20Sunshine%20Man&usprop=blockinfo%7Cgroups%7Ceditcount%7Cregistration%7Cemailable%7Cgender

which returns:

```
{
    "query": {
        "users": [
            {
                "userid": 14281125,
                "name": "December21st2012Freak",
                "editcount": 0,
                "registration": "2011-03-29T02:14:36Z",
                "groups": [
                    "*",
                    "user"
                ],
                "emailable": "",
                "gender": "unknown"
            },
            {
                "userid": 4857299,
                "name": "The Sunshine Man",
                "editcount": 0,
                "registration": "2007-07-13T20:00:58Z",
                "groups": [
                    "*",
                    "user"
                ],
                "gender": "unknown"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And the Usercontribs query:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=usercontribs&ucuser=December21st2012Freak&uclimit=3&ucdir=newer&continue=

which results:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "continue": {
        "uccontinue": "20090904033705|311775264",
        "continue": "-||"
    },
    "query": {
        "usercontribs": [
            {
                "userid": 10141256,
                "user": "December21st2012Freak",
                "pageid": 24217201,
                "revid": 311775169,
                "parentid": 0,
                "ns": 3,
                "title": "User talk:MsD723",
                "timestamp": "2009-09-04T03:36:13Z",
                "new": "",
                "minor": "",
                "top": "",
                "comment": "Added welcome template to user talk page. using [[WP:FRIENDLY|Friendly]]",
                "size": 1458
            },
            {
                "userid": 10141256,
                "user": "December21st2012Freak",
                "pageid": 24217203,
                "revid": 311775198,
                "parentid": 0,
                "ns": 3,
                "title": "User talk:Oneseeker2",
                "timestamp": "2009-09-04T03:36:32Z",
                "new": "",
                "minor": "",
                "top": "",
                "comment": "Added welcome template to user talk page. using [[WP:FRIENDLY|Friendly]]",
                "size": 1458
            },
            {
                "userid": 10141256,
                "user": "December21st2012Freak",
                "pageid": 24217208,
                "revid": 311775231,
                "parentid": 0,
                "ns": 3,
                "title": "User talk:Carolynhinchey",
                "timestamp": "2009-09-04T03:36:46Z",
                "new": "",
                "minor": "",
                "top": "",
                "comment": "Added welcome template to user talk page. using [[WP:FRIENDLY|Friendly]]",
                "size": 1458
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=usercontribs&ucuser=The%20Sunshine%20Man&uclimit=3&ucdir=newer&continue=

which results:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "continue": {
        "uccontinue": "20070517145725|131549160",
        "continue": "-||"
    },
    "query": {
        "usercontribs": [
            {
                "userid": 4302884,
                "user": "The Sunshine Man",
                "pageid": 11271016,
                "revid": 131518067,
                "parentid": 131517319,
                "ns": 4,
                "title": "Wikipedia:Miscellany for deletion/Portal:Aquinas College, Perth",
                "timestamp": "2007-05-17T11:48:17Z",
                "comment": "/* [[Portal:Aquinas College, Perth]] */ Delete",
                "size": 1773
            },
            {
                "userid": 4302884,
                "user": "The Sunshine Man",
                "pageid": 7797923,
                "revid": 131547208,
                "parentid": 131525587,
                "ns": 3,
                "title": "User talk:Ryan Postlethwaite",
                "timestamp": "2007-05-17T14:47:29Z",
                "comment": "HeHe",
                "size": 49019
            },
            {
                "userid": 4302884,
                "user": "The Sunshine Man",
                "pageid": 11247929,
                "revid": 131547970,
                "parentid": 131543922,
                "ns": 4,
                "title": "Wikipedia:Requests for adminship/Bobak",
                "timestamp": "2007-05-17T14:51:19Z",
                "comment": "Support",
                "size": 16492
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample queries?

Comment: @Tgr, I added the exact queries into the question.

Comment: Thanks! This should not be happening. I filed a bug report ([T99929](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T99929)).

Comment: The API doesn't provide gender. It only provides [grammatical gender preferences](https://translatewiki.net/wiki/Gender).

Answer (score 0):

As reported by Tgr: this is a bug, please be patient and wait for it to be fixed. https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T99929